# Why if I enter any data into edittext that data not printed in that editext in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

I am doing one app here in edittext. I need to enter some data like name but when I enter data into edittext that is not displyed. Same app I run in another system that time it's working well. But in some systems it's not working. What is the problem?

My code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="425dp"
    android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_marginLeft="290dp" android:ems="11">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: chdnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              chdnm.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
              InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
              FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20);
              chdnm.setFilters(FilterArray); this my java code

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. You had HUGE margin values. Try this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

What theme you are using? Try to change the EditText Color.

```
   chdnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
chdnm.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: in my xml file grapiclayout it showing this nelow msg                   Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme